# How to read from two separate locations of a file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I have a file descriptor created from a simple `open` call. I want to pass it to separate functions while keeping its location within the function's scope.

Let's say I have these two functions:

```
OFFSET_TABLE_OFS = 64

def next_ofs(handle):
    handle.seek(OFFSET_TABLE_OFS)
    while True:
        ofs = struct.unpack('I', handle.read(4))
        if ofs == 0xFFFF:
            return None
        yield ofs

def parse_at(handle, ofs):
    handle.seek(ofs)
    parsed_stuff = handle.read(256)
```

The problem here is that if I have a really long offset table and don't want or need to load all of it at once. In a small application, it's easy to either simply seek back to a known offset after parsing before continuing reads, but that can have so many complications. Are there any better suggestions for handling this problem?

Comment: why dont you want to just load it all at once into a struct?

Comment: You could open the same file for reading twice and then use one handle for reading offsets and the other of reading and parsing data at those various offset locations. This will effectively allow you to treat the single file as though it were two separate ones.